# Raspberry Pi 3 will not connect to wifi

Tags: raspi-config

I am a complete newbie to raspberry Pi. I have a class set of Pi's and have been able to connect some to the wifi at the school but not to others. The ones that don't work show that the wifi has connected but when you use the browser it says the connection failed.

Answer (score 0):

Some wifi network will have proxy settings and others. Maybe this would be the case. Make sure your pi is connected to the Wi-Fi network through the password

Comment: It is connected to the wifi through the password. I am also unable to connect using an Ethernet cable And sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade fails